# How can I find a subbasis of a topology which does not contain a singleton set?

Tags: general-topology

How should I prove this?

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. Find a subbasis $S$ for $T$ which does not contain any singleton sets.

$a.$ If $X$ is finite.

$b.$ If $X$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not always possible. Every subbase for the topology of the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) contains the singleton $\{1\}$. For an infinite example, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$; then

$$\tau=\{\Bbb N\}\cup\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$$

is a topology on $\Bbb N$, and every subbase for $\tau$ contains the singleton $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that I can always choose a subbasis that can generate a topology that  does not contain a singleton set through the union of each singleton sets in the subbasis.

Comment: @badet: This becomes impossible when the space has a point that is contained in **every** non-empty open set.

Comment: Here  $k \in \mathbb{N} $ , we know that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$@BrianM.Scott sir ...How every subbase for $\tau$ contains the singleton $\{0\}$.?

Comment: @jasmine: For many mathematicians, including me, $\Bbb N$ denotes the set of non-negative integers, so $0$ **is** an element of $\Bbb N$. If I want the set of strictly positive integers, I write $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @jasmine : As specified in [ISO 80000-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2), $0 \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: thanks u  @EricTowers

Comment: The essential point of why there is no subbase without a singleton: the topology is linearly ordered by inclusion, and has a minimal element that is a singleton. Because of the first fact, finite intersections of subbase elements always reduce to a single member (or $X$ for the empty one), the minimal one.