# Find a subbasis $\mathcal S$ for $\mathcal T$ such that $\mathcal S$ does not contain any singleton sets.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be any infinite and $\mathcal T$ the discrete topology on $X$. Find a subbasis $\mathcal S$ for $\mathcal T$ such that $\mathcal S$ does not contain any singleton sets.

I found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439404/how-can-i-find-a-subbasis-of-a-topology-which-does-not-contain-a-singleton-set), however, I noticed that in that question the answer does not provide an example of a subbasis $\mathcal S$ which does not contain any singleton sets, and hence not completely answering the question that I have.

Comment: Take the collection of all subsets of cardinality 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, firstly, provided from our subbasis we can get every singleton is open, we know such a subbasis generates the discrete topology (check this if you don't agree). Hence, we want to have a subbasis from which we can construct all singletons, but not containing any singletons. Further, because we want the discrete topology, we can put in *any* subset of $X$ and be safe. So, why not try $$\mathcal{S} = \{O\subseteq X: O\text{ is not a singleton}\}?$$

This isn't the only thing though, you can take all $2$ element subsets, or all finite subsets. There are many options.