# Topology which doesn't contain any singleton set

Tags: general-topology

I found the same question here but here answer is given opposite

[How can I find a subbasis of a topology which does not contain a singleton set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439404/how-can-i-find-a-subbasis-of-a-topology-which-does-not-contain-a-singleton-set)

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. Find a subbasis $S$ for $T$ which does not contain any singleton sets.

$1.$ If $X$ is finite.

$2.$ If $X$ is infinite.

My attempt : For $1).$ take discrete topology$ T$ and $X= \{ a,b,c\}$

Now $ S$ is a subbasis for $(X,T)$  if finite intersection  of member of $S $ give $\{a\}$ , $\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$. so $S=\{ \{a,b\} ,\{b,c\} ,\{a,c\} \}$ which doesnot conatin any singleton sets

Now $ \{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}= \{b\} $, similarly it will give $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$

Is its true ?

For $2).$ Im thinking like this take   Usual topology $T$ and $X= \mathbb{R}$

Take subbasis $S=[a,\infty]$  because $[a,x]$ and $[ x, \infty]$ will form subbasis which don't contain any singleton set

Is its true

Comment: The wording of the problem is wrong. The way it is stated you cannot even choose your $X$.

Comment: in my question $X$ can choose @KaviRamaMurthy sir

Comment: An example (as for the reals or your three point discrete space) is not a proof. The linked question gives a counterexample to your claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X=\{0,1\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, X\}$ (the Sierpiński topology), then no such subbase exists. This is easy to see in this case, as there are only 8 subsets of the topology and only those with $\{0\}$ in it (e.g. $\mathcal{S}=\{\{0\}\}$ itself) are subbases for $\mathcal{T}$, or use the argument from the following example..

For an infinite counterexample, take $X=\Bbb N$ and the topology $$\mathcal{T}= \{\emptyset,X\} \cup \{\downarrow m = \{n \in \Bbb N: n \le m\} \mid m \in \Bbb N\}$$ (the down-topology on $\Bbb N$) and show that all subbases for $\mathcal{T}$ include $\{0\}$ (because it is the minimal element by inclusion in the topology, which is linearly ordered). The infinite example can be seen as a generalisation of the Sierpiński example.

Answer (score 2):

If $[a,\infty]$ is using the standard notation, it is a closed set.

Then while $[a,\infty] \cap [-\infty,a] = \{a\}$ it is not the case that $\{a\}$ is an open set.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean find a topological space $(X,\cal U)$ so that $\forall x \in X$, $\{x\} \not \in \cal U$?

If so, $\Bbb N$ (the natural numbers) with the *cofinite* topology is an example, I believe.  (The cofinite topology on $\Bbb N$ consists of all $U\subset \Bbb N$ so that $\overline{U}$ is finite, together with $\emptyset$.  Of course, part of the exercise - I assume this is an exercise - is to show that this defines a topology on $\Bbb N$.)

Comment: No, he wants (an impossible) proof that every topology has such a subbase.